# Remove text via D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm attempting to update a graph based upon some dynamic data/user input on the page. Since the data is simply placed at the base of a bar graph's column and doesn't need to move, I don't think I need any animation. Simply need to remove the current text and replace with the new values.

The code below was my best guess, however it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. The `.append()` works fine, however it simply overlays the new text over the old, and it eventually just becomes unreadable (obviously). Seems like it's the `.remove()` that I'm using improperly.

Relatively new to D3.js so if there's a better way/anyone has any hints/tips they'd be appreciated.

**EDITED per comments**

```
        //Remove the old text
        this.options.barDemo.selectAll("text.eoyValue")
            .data(data)
            .exit().remove();

        //Replace with the new text           
        this.options.barDemo.selectAll("text.eoyValue")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i + .35) + barWidth; })
            .attr("y", height - 10)
            .attr("dx", -barWidth / 2)
            .attr("dy", "15px")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family; Helvetica, sans-serif")
            .text(function(d) {
                console.log(d.attributes.contract);
                return d.attributes.contract;
            })
            .attr("transform", "translate(0, 18)")
            .attr("class", "eoyValue");
```

Comment: It looks like you're never adding the class `eoyValue`, so `barDemo.selectAll("text.eoyValue")` will always be empty.

Comment: Thanks, added to the post. Unfortunately I'm running into a similar problem in that the `.remove()` call is still not picking anything up, and now the `.append()` call doesn't write any new values, they are all stuck at the `0.00` that is there when the page loads.

Comment: If I place a `console.log()` in the `.text()` function I see that the `.append()` call only fires when the page loads. Chrome's debugger shows the block of code evaluated when the values change, however the `console.log()` never works.

Answer (score 0):

So on top of not adding the class name I was also not calling the `transition()` method. The code below solved the problem.

```
        this.options.barDemo.selectAll("text.eoyValue")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i + .35) + barWidth; })
            .attr("y", height - 10)
            .attr("dx", -barWidth / 2)
            .attr("dy", "15px")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family; Helvetica, sans-serif")
            .text(function(d) { return d.attributes.contract; })
            .attr("transform", "translate(0, 18)")
            .attr("class", "eoyValue");


        var columnBaseText = this.options.barDemo.selectAll("text.eoyValue").data(data, function (d, i) {
            console.log(i);
            return i;
        });

        columnBaseText.transition()
            .duration(1100)
            .attr("y", height-10)
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.attributes.contract;
            });
```